# Is it possible to control my computer like JARVIS with WSR Macros and windows speech recognition Technology?

Tags: speech-recognition

I am new to Windows Speech Recognition Technology. I have an idea to control my system like JARVIS. For that I need to interpret my idea as Windows speech recognition Macros.

Before moving to Windows speech Recognition Macros, I have a question regarding them.

Could anyone tell me merits and demerits of windows speech recognition macros?

If I installed the windows speech recognition macros and developed commands through macros, will the system performance get affected?

Is it possible to implement my idea?

Could anyone provide a solution or suggestion for this?